# Will i still be able to access old wordpress.com site after transferring domain to self hosting

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, web-hosting, transfer

Just wondering if someone can clear something up for me. I am moving a site to another hosting provider for a friend who had their blog hosted on wordpress.com but had bought their own domain through them so the `"wordpress.com"` extension wasn't displayed.

I have transferred the new domain and I'm waiting for the `DNS records` to propagate. In the backend of the Wordpress site I have since changed the default domain to be `"blogname.wordpress.com"`

What I'm wondering is after the `DNS records` have propagated and the transferred domain now points to the new hosting will I still be able to access the `wordpress.com` site?

Or does this disappear?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you do with your old WordPress website. At WordPress.com dashboard you will have multiple options like:

Delete Site
Change your site’s address and keep your content
Empty your site of all its content for a fresh start
Transfer your website to someone else
Make your site private so only people you invite can see it

Usually, WordPress.com users set 301 redirection to self hosted domain. This way you will not lose any traffic or links pointing to your site. WordPress.com offers an add-on call site-redirect which cost only $13/year and it offers 301 perma-redirect.